# SQL change DATEADD data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to round a time column to quarters, I searched the forum and found this nice code:

```
 select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0)
```

The problem is this gives me the time as a timestamp column, with date 1900-01-01, while I only want this as a time. I can't find how to do this.

Comment: You didn't specify which version of SQL Server you are using. Since SQL Server 2008 we have had the **time** data type (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.100).aspx). You can therefore just `Cast(... As time)`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which version of SQL Server you are using.

Since SQL Server 2008 we have had the **time** data type (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.100).aspx).

```
SELECT DateAdd(mi, DateDiff(mi, 0, GetDate()) / 15 * 15, 0) As original_value
     , Convert(time, DateAdd(mi, DateDiff(mi, 0, GetDate()) / 15 * 15, 0)) As sql_2008_onwards
     , Convert(char(10), DateAdd(mi, DateDiff(mi, 0, GetDate()) / 15 * 15, 0), 108) As pre_sql_2008
```

With the last option, your final value is still a piece of text. Ideally you should convert it back in to a `datetime` value (`Convert(datetime, <rest of code>)`)

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful to you.

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime

SET @datetime = (select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0))

SELECT CAST(DATEPART(hour, @datetime) as varchar(2)) + 
':' +  CAST(DATEPART(minute, @datetime)as varchar(2))
```

Comment: thx! I am quite new to SQL, and have been wondering this for some time the, @ character means a custom build function?

Comment: '@' to specify the local variable. '@@' to specify the global variable

Comment: @ prefix is used for local variable in TSQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
               dateadd(minute,
               datediff(minute,0,GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0),
               108)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **convert** method to get the time.

```
SELECT 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
      dateadd(minute, 
      datediff(minute ,0,GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0), 
      108)
```

108 in the above query show the **Time format**. You can change it based on your requirement.

You can learn more here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(minute,
       DATEDIFF(minute, 0, GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0) AS TIME(0));
```